# Launch two android emulators from two eclipse workspace

Tags: android, android-emulator

**Problem Statement:-**

I have two `Eclipse Workspace`.

In my first eclipse workspace, I have one project which I have launched on one emulator and I can see my application on that emulator and it is working fine over there. I have **Always prompt to pickup device** settings enabled. As soon as I launch the application I pick my first emulator which is `Hack1`.

In my second eclipse workspace, I have the same project as well but with some minor UI changes into that. Now I am trying to launch my application on another emulator(same configuration as first emulator but with a new name). But as soon as I try to launch that application, my second emulator is not getting launched?. In this case, As soon as I launch the application I pick my second emulator which is `Hack2`.

I am not sure what is the problem. I tried several times?

Anyone is aware of what can be the possible problem?

I am just trying to launch emulator from one eclipse workspace and other emulator from other eclipse workspace. But they both are same projects only with some minor changes into that.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did you change run as configurations?

Comment: what I need to change in run as configurations? I have Always prompt to pickup device setting enabled. Whenever I try to launch applicaiton, it asks me to pick the emulator. And I am picking the other emulator as well. But it's not launching.

Comment: Did you try launching the emulator manually and then installing the apk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what i can suggest you that first you kill-the process which running..
follow these steps...
step 1:open command prompt
step 2:type adb kill-server
step 3:type adb start-server
then you clear your project and run it...